# minus "-" sign not working css content '\f117' is not working recently

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-3.2

**How to make old version fontawesome3 work**

I am using css content to show - symbol in my page. I have used below code and it was working fine before. But recently noticed that content: "\f117"; does not show my symbol.

Why is this happening now? Has the unicode representing this character changed? I have not included any additional css file.

```
.test-thiselemtn:before {
    content: "\f117";
}
```

**Update1:-**
Updating the question.

How to make old version fontawesome 3.2.1 work, that is, -ve sign of unicode **content '\f117'** be displayed correctly.
Also, has this anything to do with eot woff and ttf files?

**Update2:-**

**How to make two versions of fontawesome v3.2.1 and v4.. work together?**

Comment: Where did you find `\f117` unicode? this could be font family issue.

Comment: further dig-ed into the code and found src fontaweseom-webfont.eot?v3.. included.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode for - symbol in font awesome is \f068. If it doesn't load by then too, then use font-family: FontAwesome in your CSS.

```
.test-thiselemtn:before{ content: "\f068"; font-family: FontAwesome;}
```

If you don't want to use font awesome  then you can use

```
.test-thiselememtn:before{ content: "\2012";}
```